# Why changing a function argument reflects to the main value that is I passed to that function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

I have tried to create a BLACKJACK game using python (actually I'm learning python). Currently I have not setup bet command (that is written in my Account class). I only takes name from my Account class.

I have a main file : blackjack.py
and two classes in files : deckofcards.py, account.py
I am only accessing name from account class, so I wont be putting that long mess here.

blackjack.py :

```
from account import Account

player = Account('kalaLokia')
cards = DeckOfCards()
play = False
playershand = []
dealershand = []
action = ''
blackjack = False


def showCards(items, name):
    '''
    Shows {name}'s cards and hand value
    '''
    print(f"{name}'s hand: ")
    print(f"\t{' - '.join(items)}")
    print(f"Hand value: {cards.handValue(items)}")


def bust(hand):
    '''
    Whether a someone has busted or not
    '''
    if(cards.handValue(hand) > 21):
        return True
    return False


def dealersMove():
    '''
    Dealers move: executes when player calls "stand"
    Dealer perform hit until he gets bust, wins or his hand value becomes >= 17
    When hand value is >17 and players has greater value, dealer loses ;-)
    '''
    global blackjack

    if(cards.handValue(dealershand) == 21):
        print('Dealer got a BLACKJACK')
        print('Dealer WINS')
        return
    elif(blackjack):
        print(f'{player.name} got a BLACKJACK')
        print(f'{player.name} WINS')
        blackjack=False
        return

    while(not bust(dealershand)):

        if(cards.handValue(dealershand) > cards.handValue(playershand)):
            print('Dealer WINS')
            showCards(dealershand, 'Dealer')
            break
        elif(cards.handValue(dealershand) == cards.handValue(playershand)):
            print("It's a TIE!!\n Dealer WINS")
            break
        elif(cards.handValue(dealershand) > 17):
            print(f'Dealer loses\n{player.name} has WON.')
            print(f'{cards.handValue(playershand)} > {cards.handValue(dealershand)}')
            break

        dealershand.append(cards.hit())
    else:
        print(f'Dealer busts! \n{player.name} has WON the game.')


def start():
    '''
    The actiona that can be performed
    '''
    global blackjack

    if(cards.handValue(playershand) == 21): 
        blackjack = True
        dealersMove()
        return
    while(not bust(playershand)):

        action = input(
            f"{player.name}'s turn: Do you want to hit or stand ? ").lower()
        if(action == 'hit'):
            playershand.append(cards.hit())
            showCards(playershand, player.name)
        elif(action == 'stand'):
            dealersMove()
            break
        else:
            print('Please enter a valid action !')
    else:
        print(f'{player.name} has been BUSTED')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(f'Hello {player.name}, Welcome to BlackJack Game')
    # Tell game rules here, may be
    response = input('Do you want to start the game (Y/n)? ').lower()
    if(response != 'y'):
        play = False
        print('You have been exited the game')
    else:
        play = True
    # Ask for bet amount later
    while(play):
        cards = DeckOfCards()
        cards.shuffle()
        print('Cards on the table is now shuffled')
        playershand = list(cards.initiate())
        dealershand = list(cards.initiate())
        print(
            f"{player.name}'s hand:\n   {playershand[0]} - {playershand[1]}\nHand value: {cards.handValue(playershand)}\n")
        print(f"Dealer's hand:\n   {dealershand[0]} - ?\n")

        start()

        if(input('Do you want to play again (Y/n)?').lower() != 'y'):
            print('The End')
            play = False
```

deckofcards.py :

```
import random

class DeckOfCards():
    '''
    All talks here is about cards
    '''
    cards = {'A':11,'K':10,'Q':10,'J':10,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10}

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Initialize deck of cards
        '''
        self.deck = list(self.cards.keys())*4

    def shuffle(self):
        '''
        Simply shuffles the deck of cards
        '''
        return random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def handValue(self, hand):
        '''
        Calculates and returns the hand value, expecting a string value to be feeded.
        '''
        result = 0

        for element in hand:
            result = result + self.cards[element]

        while('A' in hand and result > 21):
            if(hand[0]=='A'):
                result = result - 10
            # Somehow this hand.pop is poping out from main value itself. Why ???
            hand.pop(0)

            if(hand == []):
                break  

        return result

    def hit(self):
        '''
        Pop out and returns the last card in the deck
        '''
        return self.deck.pop()

    def initiate(self):
        '''
        Pop out 2 cards from the deck and return as a tuple
        '''
        return (self.deck.pop(), self.deck.pop() )
```

**Issue:**
When I have an ACE in my hand and my hand value is greater than 21, the while condition executes in the `handValue` function *(which is in DeckofCards class)* as it is. Problem is, after that `while` condition executes, `playershand` *(declared in main file)* I just passed to this `handValue` function gets empty. That is the `hand.pop(0)` actually seems popping out value from main object `playershand` itself (It seems me so).

When I press a hit after that, I get a single new card, all other cards are got popped out. I don't understand why it is so.

On hit(user enter hit) : actually I am passing `playershand` (cards on the player hand,  it's a list) to function `showCards` *(which is also in the main file)* where it takes it as argument items and pass it to `handValue` function in the class `DeckOfCards`.

So why is it happening? even though I am passing playershand as an argument to other functions, how pop() function affecting playershand which has only access to hand object in the handValue class ?

I have my complete code in [github repo](https://github.com/kalaLokia/kalaLearns) to test out, the files in folder blackjack

Comment: Passing a parameter to a function *doesn't make a copy of it* - that would be horribly inefficient.  It's the same object inside the function as in the caller of the function.

Comment: So you're saying `hand` object in the function `handValue` is same of `playershand` which I passed to it ? I know the value will be same, but how it is possible that modifying `hand` also reflecting back to `playershand`. I am not returning the modified `hand` value to anywhere. @jasonharper

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/12637074 : This described me everything I wanted to know